# Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/09. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, wordpress

I am facing this issue while uploading a theme.I have tried almost all the solutions given in forums of changing permissions and all.Still the issue hasn't been resolved.I need to make the website in a weeks time.Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

To have a directory writable by the web server you would have to ensure the directory is writer by the server's userID.

On Ubuntu the server is run by userID `www-data`.

Go to the directory where you want the server to have write access and change the owner and group to `www-data`.  Your error message is saying parent directory.  So you will have to be sure to do this for the parent directory of where the file is actually running.

**Run this command on your wp-content directory:**

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content
```

That will change the owner of wp-content as well as all the other files and directories including the `uploads/2016/09` and their subdirectory to be owned by the web server and resolve the error.